# Fixing simple PHP WordPress user display name script

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress

I have PHP script that displays all of the posts from a WordPress database. The script then takes the author's user ID and queries it in the user table of the database to find out their display name. **However, this is currently only working for the first result. Why is this?**

```
<?

mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db('database');

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo'<p><h3>'.$row[post_title].'</h3><br>';

$user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID='$row[post_author]'");
while($u=mysql_fetch_array($user)){
echo $u[display_name];
}
echo' </p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Be prepared for people telling you to not use the `mysql_` functions; they are obsolete.  If you rewrite your query like `SELECT * FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_users ON (wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID) WHERE post_type = 'post'` you will only need one query to get everything.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you change you're query to

```
Select users.display_name, posts.post_title 
FROM wp_posts posts 
inner join wp_users users on posts.post_author = users.ID
where posts.post_type = 'post';
```

That will get rid of a ton of DB calls. What exactly isn't working for any result other than the first? Are you sure you have more than 1 post in the wp_posts table?

Comment: Try changing the query to what I suggested, and then get rid of the 2nd query and while loop. You can just have `echo '<p><h3>'.$row[post_title].'</h3><br>' . $row[display_name] . '</p>';`. You should also use quotes to reference associative arrays, ie `$row['post_title']`.

Comment: It means that your wp_users table only has one record with an ID that is the same as post_author field in the posts table.

Comment: You have the query right, you just need to make sure that there are records in your wp_users table. Look at each record in your wp_posts table, specifically at the post_author value. Are all of those post_author values in the wp_users table, specifically the ID field?